# Required item type of value of parameter is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below XML

```
<content.text.block>
<text.line>context1</text.line>
<text.line>context2</text.line>
<text.line>context3</text.line>
<text.line>context4</text.line>
<text.line>context5</text.line>
<text.line>context6</text.line>
<text.line suppress-flag="y">context7</text.line>
</content.text.block>
```

below is the xslt code i am using

```
<xsl:for-each select="$textline[not(@suppress-flag = 'y')]">
  <xsl:call-template name="populatetextNumber">
  <xsl:with-param name="textNumber" select="current()" as="node()"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
 <xsl:for-each select="$textline[@suppress-flag = 'y']">
  <xsl:call-template name="populatetextNumber">
  <xsl:with-param name="textNumber" select="current()" as="node()"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

$textline contains the values within the "text.line" element.

the first for-each works fine. but the second for-each throws the below error.

"Required item type of value of parameter $textNumber is node(); supplied value  has item type xs:string".

For the elements without any attributes, the code seems to work fine. But when it comes to elements with attributes its an issue

Using 'as="node()"' also didn't help

Comment: Please post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `as="node()"` here?

Comment: I believe that you are selecting the string value of the text.line element .. not the element itself. The fact that the first for-each works could be just due to the _not_ condition.Could you show us how you set the value of the `$textline` variable ?

Comment: I'm quite baffled by the error, since if `$textNumber` is a string, then `$textline` must be a string, and if `$textline` is a string, then the predicate `[@suppress-flag='y']` will give you a different error ("context item is not a node"). But as others have said, debugging your code is difficult when you've left out the critical information.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is a type mismatch between the parameter `textNumber` of the named template `populatetextNumber` and the value you are passing for that parameter, which is a string.  (This much should be obvious to your from the error message; if not, read the error message again until you understand what it is saying.)

You say

> $textline contains the values within the "text.line" element.

If this is correct (and I guess it is, since it fits with what the error message is saying), then $textline will contain either one string, or a sequence of strings.   Iterating over that sequence of strings with a for-each won't change any of them into a tree node.

If you want to pass the template `populatetextNumber` a node as a parameter, then change either the `select` expression for the for-each to select the `text.line` elements, or else the declaration of `$textline` to make it a sequence of elements, not a sequence of strings.

If for whatever reason you want to keep $textline and the for-each as they are, you need to change the named template `populatetextNumber` to accept a string, not a node, as the value of its `textNumber` parameter.

---

Note that many who answer questions on Stack Overflow dislike questions which omit information of obvious relevance.  Your question would be better (and more likely to get quick answers) if you had included the declaration of the variable `$textline` (since its actual type is part of the problem) and at least the parameter declarations for the named template `populatetextNumber` (since its declared type is the other part of the type conflict).  When you omit information like that, some readers of Stack Overflow will infer that you either don't know enough to ask a coherent question (good advice in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), or that you don't care enough  about the answerers' time to give them the information they need.  That inference may not be fair, but it's compatible with all the information you have provided.